# Prevent HTML Select/Option from reseting after jQuery Post

Tags: php, jquery, html, web-applications

I seem to have a weird situation. Description of problem below.

In my web application, I have three tabs where the user can enter and view information. The main tabs include : List, Time Preference, and Search Results. In the Time Preference tab are a series of drop down select options that the user can select from (maybe about 30 or more dropDown boxes), the options themselves are generated from a php script.

[image: Small Image]

Portion of the script I'm using to generate the options.

```
<?php
// Create options for hour
for($i = 1; $i < 13; $i++)
   $hourOptions.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$i\">".$i.'</option>';
?>
```

I have a GENERATE button at the bottom of the Time Preference tab which $.post all of my data from my List and Time Preference drop down boxes with the help of jQuery imported from a separate JS file. Only problem is, is that my drop down boxes reset when I go back to the previous tab. It will generate just fine, and my List is still retained, however all of my dropdown boxes reset.

This is how I am retrieving the selected data in my JS file. The convert is what I use to convert to a 24hr time, so that can be ignored. There are also about 10-15 of these lines allowing for different schedules, and so they all get posted to a PHP file, using $.post. I've tested using ALERT, and spitting out the time. Before the $.post I am able to retrieve it just fine, however, after the $.post it's blank. Any hint/tip would be certainly be helpful. Whether it be a way to set the selected option to it's original state after the post, or just prevent it from occurring in the first place.

```
MWFStart = convertTime($('#MWFStartHour').val(),$('#MWFStartMinute').val(),$('#MWFStartMeridian').val());
```

Comment: Firstly -- Thanks Matt for cleaning that up. Secondly, can we see the $post code, and the structure of the DOM, starting from the container for the "Three main Tabs". You can toss it all together in a http://jsfiddle.net/, or http://pastebin.org if it's huge.

Comment: Here is my HTML part for the 3 tabs: http://pastebin.com/Q1K6CaTY
and my $.post code: http://pastebin.com/Z8AaQu8g

If you require further explanation, just let me know. Really appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: Okay, and sorry to ask, but just to be clear -- you are using return false or preventDefault(), or stopPropagation() in your handler statement for whatever performs the post, right?

Comment: I'm not using the preventDefault(). How would that be handled in the event that the option is set to the default by the user, would it still be prevented?

Comment: well I'm just asking because I don't know if you use a form submit handler, or if you just use a select list handler and post the variables yourself. Which method are you using?

Comment: I created buttons through the jQuery UI, on the press of those buttons using methods such as $(#MWFStart).val() to retrieve the item selected and store them in to temporary variables to later post them. MWFStart being the ID of the Select tag in HTML.

Comment: Okay. I get the retrieval method, but what about the invocation method? Are you using $("#form").submit(function(){, or are you using $("#select").change(function(){ to invoke your $.post?

Comment: It's based on a click (submit). http://pastebin.com/9vrhj07r

So, on the press of the button, all of the data comes together, and get's posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your

```
$("#whatever").click(function(){
```

add an "e", so:

```
$("#whatever").click(function(e){
```

then use the preventDefault() method to stop the default action the submission.

```
$("#whatever").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
```

See if that gives you any help.